# Formatting Money in Rails Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm creating an App where people can create products, and sell them via Stripe. I'm wondering how I can format my input on my form so that 600 is equal to £600, and not £6. I'm also going to be creating products in many different currencies, so do not want to hack away at decimals.

```
<%= f.input :price %>
```

I have the Money gem installed to show the correct price once saved, but I'm just having trouble with the form when creating products.

Comment: I am not so clear about the question, however, I think you are looking for `number_to_currency` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency

Comment: @RAJ I'm inputting my price as "60000" if I want to charge $600 and I want to be able to just put 600, as this will be used by members of staff.

Comment: Sorry, do you want to set maximum allowed value in the field??

Comment: @RAJ No. Stripe charges in cents, so 600 is $6. However my staff will be entering the actual price of the product, so I need 600 to charge $600 in Stripe.

Comment: Ah! got it. You should multiple entered value with 100 before sending data to sprite. Another thing, when you will support other currencies, you will need to manage

Comment: @RAJ But I'm using multiple currencies at the moment, so it will just brake when I enter a product w/ Honk Kong Dollars for example.

Comment: I can see that you can call subunit method on your `Money` object. E.g.: `money = Money.new(AMOUNT, "USD") money.cents`

Answer (score 2):

The [Money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money#rubymoney---money) lets you do all these things. It includes a [I18n](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money#i18n) feature also allowing you to use it in many different currencies.

The rails version is: [money-rails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#rubymoney---money-rails-)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the Money gem has made a real dangerous decision in the API design. It looks counter-intuitive. I would not use it. 
Even if you get this right now, some day you or some of your coworker may forget this detail, the code will look good, but the result will be wrong by factor 100.

Even just using floats will be less dangerous, as the error when you make the rounding is wrong will be much smaller (and rounding is not easy to get right, as commercial rounding and mathematical rounding give sometimes different results)